# c++ template method definition does not recognise using alias

Tags: c++, templates

I am declaring a template class and defining the methods on an inline file

(foo.hpp)

```
template<typename T>
class Foo {
public:
  using Result = T::Result;

  Foo();
  ~Foo();

  Result Bar();
};
```

(foo-inl.hpp)

```
template<typename T>
Result Foo<T>::Bar() {
  ...
}
```

But I get an error

`error: 'Result' does not name a type;`

I thought, since i declare `Bar` as part of `Foo<T>` the method definition should know about `Result`

Any suggestons on how to fix it?

Comment: TL;DR of the dupe: `using Result = T::Result;` needs to be `using Result = typename T::Result;` to tell the compiler the dependent name is a type.  Otherwise it assumes it is an object.

Comment: Also, `Result Foo<T>::Bar()` needs to be `Foo<T>::Result Foo<T>::Bar() ` as `Result` is scoped to `Foo`.

Comment: You would need `Foo<T>::Result` or simply `T::Result` since at the point of mentioning `Result` you are not inside `Foo<T>` scope.